# Can someone tell me why this question is voted to be closed?

Tags: discussion

https://serverfault.com/questions/354707/how-to-create-my-own-ssl-proxy

I'm sorry I asked the question as I thought it was related to SERVER, because I thought I should install some software package such as Squid or something on my VPS server and then it would act like an SSL proxy which I can use on my local computer.

Can someone please tell me what the right direction is? So creating an SSL proxy wasn't server-related? Why?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two big reasons:

1. It isn't clear if this is for a professional workplace solution.
2. As written, it looks like you're trying to bypass a security policy in place by your government, which probably makes it illegal.

The second point is the biggest one. Security policy circumvention, all politics aside, is off topic here.

As an aside: we're revising our FAQ, and the new, better draft-copy is found [here](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/2592/3038). It has more clarity on some points relevant to your interests.