# Is it possible to make a post "sticky"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

From time to time things with a higher than normal level of importance and/or time sensitivity get posted here. e.g. The election and FAQ discussion. On a BBS such things would be made sticky to ensure they don't slide down the list, possibly into oblivion. Is it possible to do likewise here? (By "here" I mean meta.)

I would assume the stickiness would be removed when it's no longer required.

Comment: A bit old, but: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9112/sticky-able-questions-on-meta

Comment: Is the featured tag like sysadmin1138 set on http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2809/voting-on-the-faq-rewrite not enough?

Comment: @Zoredache, I'm talking about a way to keep important posts at the top of the list, regardless of how a user may sort it. The `featured` tag is after all just another tag and being the same colour as `status-completed` actually means it's more likely to be overlooked by those in a hurry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can add a post notice just to meta, like the election one, but that's all we can do I think.

Comment: Would it be worth requesting it as a feature? I've been monitoring the FAQ question and feel it deserves more prominence than "ordinary" posts.

Comment: Please don't abuse of the system notice makes people ignore it, then they miss important things, like downtime notifications

Comment: @Zypher, so you don't think the election and FAQ discussion are important enough?

Comment: @JohnGardeniers honestly no, not for a non-dismisable system message (although to be fair we don't have a _good_ alternative). IMNSHO Those messages should only be for critical things that everyone MUST know about like the sites are going down at x time, we are in read only mode, etc.

Comment: @Zypher, I'm not really talking about a system message though. I'm talking about a way to (temporarily) keep a post at the top of the page, which amongst other things is a **lot** less annoying.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers sorry was responding to Mark's answer and not your feature request. I believe a similar "sticky thread" request brought about the featured tag.